# Redirect 301 htaccess refactoring

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have to redirect a lot of similar url which ends with the same string.

```
eg:
Redirect 301 /url.html/string www.mydomain.it/url.html
Redirect 301 /url-2.html/string www.mydomain.it/url-2.html
Redirect 301 /url-3.html/string www.mydomain.it/url-3.html
```

I want to avoid to replicate this to N similar url and I need a unique method to delete "string". there's a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect directive appends sub paths to its destination url. 
You need to use RedirectMatch to avoid it .

```
RedirectMatch ^/([^.]+)\.html/(.+)$ http://example.com/$1.html
```